# Saving a table in HUE from a script executed on the Cloudera Workbench onto my laptop using R

Tags: r, hadoop, cloudera, hue

So I have a script written in R that pulls a table, named claims, from HUE. I now need to save that table onto my laptop. I tried this line:

```
readr::write_csv(claims, "C:/Users/user_name/Desktop/claims.csv")
```

But go this error message:

```
Error in open.connection(path, "wb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(path, "wb") :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/A0765618/Desktop/claims.csv': No such file or directory
```

Comment: I´m pretty sure you still have that file open with excel or notepad++ ?!

Comment: @MarkusLnGa I do not understand your comment?

Comment: The error message you give is the same as you would get if the directory `C:/Users/A0765618/Desktop` does not exist. (You get a different error message if the file is open in another application.)

Comment: Your file seem to be open, i guess this is why you can not open a connection.

Comment: @MarkusLnGa Which file seems to be opened? claims.csv? This file currently does not exist. I am name the new file with this name?

Comment: Ok, thought you maybe used the code twice or so. Sorry, have no idea then :-(

Comment: It's not clear where `claims` was defined, but apparently the file cannot be written to... And Hue is just a user interface, meaning files are not stored locally... Do you mean Hive or Impala?

Comment: @cricket_007 It should be Impala